# two columns with auto_increment

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I want my table look like this with only imputing the comment value:

```
ID ID2 Comment
1  1   Hi!
2  2   Hi!
```

Comment: Just use 1 auto increment column, then when running select query, select the id twice, ex: ```SELECT id, id2 AS id, comment FROM tablename```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I'm with Kristian here; just store the ID once. Storing it twice would even violate normalization as you could always determine one ID by looking at the other. Or do you want to change one of the values later (i.e. is this only the initial value that is subject to change)? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Having multiple identity columns can be useful in some cases. For example, one id the internal "key" of the table, while others are suitable to be exposed to external services. They don't need all to be keys of the table, and their value does not need to be the same either; actually it's useful when they are different, for security purposes.

Comment: What is the goal? Why do you need TWO autoincrements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention your database, so this answers tackles the general problem.

Most databases support a single identity column per table. The only database [I know of] that supports multiple identity columns is PostgreSQL. Hurray PostgreSQL!

Here's an example:

```
create table t (
  id1 int generated always as identity,
  id2 int generated always as identity,
  comment varchar(50)
);

insert into t (comment) values ('Hi Anna');
insert into t (comment) values ('Hi Peter');

select * from t;
```

Result:

```
id1  id2  comment
---  ---  --------
  1    1  Hi Anna 
  2    2  Hi Peter
```

Note that by default thay all start at 1, but each generation can have different parameters. Namely, they can start on a different starting point, different limit, cycle, etc.